# Passing multiple columns of a 2D array into a lambda function and returning a single column array

Tags: python, numpy, lambda, multidimensional-array

I am missing something simple here. I cannot figure out how to pass multiple columns of a 2D  array (matrix) and output them as a single column array.

Here is a simple example:

```
import numpy as np

Z = lambda x1,x2: (x1*x2 - 3)^2 + 1

# a sample 2D array with 15 rows and 2 columns    
x= np.arange(30).reshape((15,2))

answer = [Z(i[0],i[1]) for i in x]
```

The last line of code is where my problem lies. I would like the output to be a single column array with 15 rows.

As a final note: My code only uses 2 columns as inputs. If it could be further expanded to a flexible number of columns, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the end I don't know what you want to do, but are you aware that you could do the same operation with numpy leaving out the for loop? which would be: (x[:,0]*x[:,1] -3 )^2 + 1. Also x*x would be x**2 instead of x^2 (if you were intentionally doing that please forgive me)

Comment: Oh and if you really need columns you could do ((x[:,0]*x[:,1] -3 )^2 + 1)[np.newaxis,:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you make your last line:

```
answer = np.array([Z(i[0],i[1]) for i in x]).reshape(15,1)
```

which gives:

```
array([[ -2],
       [  0],
       [ 18],
       [ 36],
       [ 70],
       [104],
       [154],
       [204],
       [270],
       [336],
       [418],
       [500],
       [598],
       [696],
       [810]])
```

Comment: If you wanted to get rid of the 15 (because the size of the array might change) you could also do .reshape(-1,1) or np.array([[Z(i[0],i[1]) for i in x]]) (note the double [[ ]])

Comment: As a note numpy strives to avoid explicit for loops. Using numpy in this way will actually slow down your calculation.

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
import numpy as np

Z = lambda data, i, j: ((data[:,i]*data[:,j] - 3)**2 + 1)[:,np.newaxis]

# a sample 2D array with 15 rows and 2 columns    
x= np.arange(30).reshape((15,2))

answer = Z(x,0,1)
```

so maybe you don't need the lambda function after all